# Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()` Error in dplyr in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

[image]

As shown in image, i have a .csv file. I am trying to create charts. I pass dataframe from this image to a function multi_bar(dt)

The code uses a FOR LOOP and take column 1 (PS) and column 2 (APS1) in one go and then using column 1 (PS) and then column 2(APS2) by using for loop and dplyr. Basically I need column 1 in each iteration but the other column will keep changing from 2,3 and so on. The code here doesn't show code for chart but the error is coming when the code reaches column 3 (i=3) in for loop iteration. It works for i=2.

```
multi_bar=function(dt)
{
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  for(i in 2:ncol(dt))
  {
    col1 = names(dt)[1]
    col2=names(dt[i])
    
    #df=select(x,x[,1], x[,i])
    df=dt[,c(1,i)]
    df1=df%>%
      group_by(df[,1], df[,i])%>%
      summarize(n=n())
    
    colnames(df1) <- c(col1,col2,'Count')
    col3=names(df1)[3]
   
    ls=list(df1,col1,col2,col3,ncol(dt))
    
}  
    
  return(ls)     
}
```

when I pass dataframe to this function multi_bar, as shown in image (after reading csv file), the following error occurs

Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
i `..2 = df[, i]`.
x undefined columns selected
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
i `..2 = df[, i]`.
x undefined columns selected
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: So what happens when you run `rlang::last_error()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll greatly benefit by bringing the data in long (tidy) format. Then you can use `count` to count number of times each value occurs in the column.

We don't have your data to test but it would be something like this -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- dt %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = -PS) %>%
        count(PS, name, value, name = 'Count')
```